# UIImageView animated rotation

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, cgaffinetransform, cabasicanimation

I would like to rotate an UIImageView clockwise around his center after pressing a button (360 degrees)... It should be an animation... So its getting a steering wheel, and it should rotate by itself visible for the user...

I saw there are many ways to do that, but nothing worked for me... :-)

The CABasicAnimation, do I have to add a framework for this?

Could someone give me a sample code, for rotating an UIImageView around its center for (360 degrees) that works?!?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1):

Hear given below i do same thing ...... but my requirement is when touchBegin that View will be rotate 360 degree ... it may help to you.....

```
 - (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*)touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event {

    self.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self   cache:YES];
   [UIView commitAnimations];
  [delegate changeImage:self];

 }
 -(void)changeImage:(DraggableImages *)selectedView
 {
count++;
clickCounter++;
counterLable.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",clickCounter];
selectedView.image=[images objectAtIndex:selectedView.tag];
if (count==1) {
    firstSelectedView=selectedView;
}
if (count==2) {
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
    secondSelectedView=selectedView;
    count=0;
    [self performSelector:@selector(compareImages) withObject:nil     afterDelay:0.7];
}

}
  -(void)compareImages
 {
if (firstSelectedView.tag==secondSelectedView.tag) 
{
    matches++;
    //NSLog(@"%@",matches);
    Score=Score+10;
    scoreLable.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",Score];

    firstSelectedView.alpha=0.5;
    secondSelectedView.alpha=0.5;
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    if(matches==[images count])
    {

        [timer invalidate];
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:nil message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Do you want to countinue?"] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"YES",@"NO", nil];
        [alertView show];
        [alertView release];

    } 
}

else {
    Score=Score-1;
    scoreLable.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",Score];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:firstSelectedView cache:YES];
    firstSelectedView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"box.jpg"];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:NO];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:secondSelectedView cache:YES];
    secondSelectedView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"box.jpg"];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
    firstSelectedView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    secondSelectedView.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    self.view.userInteractionEnabled=YES;





}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the [`QuartzCore`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreRefCollection/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004291) framework, and you can read more about [`CABasicAnimation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CABasicAnimation_class/Introduction/Introduction.html).

### Some Tutorials

[Interrupting Animation Progress](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/11/05/core-animation-tutorial-interrupting-animation-progress/)

[Slider Based Layer Rotation](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/10/25/core-animation-tutorial-slider-based-layer-rotation/)

[CABasicAnimation basics](http://ios-blog.co.uk/iphone-development-tutorials/app-design-tip-cabasicanimation-basics/)

[Core Animation Paths](http://watchingapple.com/2008/04/core-animation-paths/)

Answer (score 0):

Upon button press invoke this method:

```
- (void) animate{

CABasicAnimation *imageRotation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation"];
imageRotation.removedOnCompletion = NO; // Do not turn back after anim. is finished
imageRotation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;

imageRotation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:((360*M_PI)/180)];

imageRotation.duration = 1.5;
imageRotation.repeatCount = 1;

[yourImageView.layer setValue:imageRotation.toValue forKey:imageRotation.keyPath];
[yourImageView.layer addAnimation:imageRotation forKey:@"imageRotation"];
```

}

and yes as WrightsCS has stated, you will need QuartzCore framework included in your project. Dont forget the import statement:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
```